# Best method to segment a given image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, machine-learning

I have one image. I want to segment it by simple approach. Could you suggest to me the best method to segment it? I think one of them is gradient or FCM. But I am not sure. Please see  my given image file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptym1zik6j35fq4/imagetest.mat)
and segmented image file below[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a segmentation, you might want to use graphcuts:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision

However lately there have been better algorithms proposed, such as Branch and Mincut:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/994e80f7-007b-4fed-a6e9-db5f4f32ccd1/

For most of the methods, source codes are available and you could try them out of the box. Also check out:
http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/

Comment: Graph cut is very complex and large computation time. I don't think we can use graph cut.

Comment: First of all, your question doesn't say anything about computational time. 

If it's an issue, then simply use graph based image segmentation:
http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/

This is very efficient.

Comment: @tibirdal: Thank you so much. I downloaded it. Very nice source code. I have schedule to do it in matlab. But I think I must make mex command. Do you know how to build it in matlab ? Because to build in Linux, the author used make file

Comment: You should use a MEX file of course. Or make an exe, which you could invoke from MATLAB. Exe could read a specific path and output to specific path. There are many options of course.